# Lighttpd 301 issue

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, lighttpd

Facebook now adds to its links a parameter like this:

```
http://www.page.com/news/?fb_action_ids=3727229231866&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=etc...
```

I can rewrite in Apache the url and make a "**301 redirect**" if I find the parameter "**fb_action_ids**". If I don’t do it, I allways got a "404 error"

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.)fb_action_ids(.)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]**
```

But now my site is on a **lighttpd server**, and I tried a thousand ways (using **url.redirect**) but my lighttpd abilities are a bit limited.

Can any expert show me how can I do the same in lighttpd?

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "fb_action_ids" {
        url.redirect = (
                "^/(.*)" => "/$1"
        )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it doesn't work :(
It doesn't detect the query string. It works if I delete the '?', but it makes a "301 redirect" itself.

Comment: Why should this work? Does everything after the /? get removed with this regex?

Answer (score 0):

`$HTTP["url"]` matches against (percent-decoded) url-path, without the query string.

`$HTTP["query-string"]` matches against (percent-encoded) the query string.

`url.redirect` matches against (percent-encoded) request target, including both url-path and query-string.

The following redirects the request to the same path, but without the query-string:

```
$HTTP["query-string"] =~ "fb_action_ids=" {
        url.redirect = (
                "" => "${url.path}"
        )
}
```